# LINQ to SQL join generates SQL which joins on IS NULL

Tags: c#, .net, linq, join

I am not good at Linq expression, today I am running into one weird issue as the below of inner join statement,

```
var orders = (from q in dao.CurrentDBContext.New_OrderForm 
              join d in dao.CurrentDBContext.New_OrderGoodsDetail on q.billNum equals d.billNum
              select new
             {    
                q.billNum,
                q.orderSource,
                q.sourceOddNum    
                d.PPT    
             }
```

While I traced the linq statement, I am confused of that `Entity Framework` will convert the linq statement to the below sql statment

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[billNum] AS [billNum], 
[Extent1].[orderSource] AS [orderSource], 
[Extent1].[sourceOddNum] AS [sourceOddNum], 
[Extent2].[PPT] AS [PPT]
FROM [dbo].[New_OrderForm] AS [Extent1]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[New_OrderGoodsDetail] AS [Extent2] 
           ON ([Extent1].[billNum] = [Extent2].[billNum]) OR 
              (([Extent1].[billNum] IS NULL) AND ([Extent2].[billNum] IS NULL))
```

Do you know why the below SQL segment did automatically append?

**OR (([Extent1].[billNum] IS NULL) AND ([Extent2].[billNum] IS NULL)**"

I don't expect that the above  automatically append, since it did slow down SQL performance. Any suggestions?

Comment: What is the **type** of `q.billNum` and `d.billNum`?

Comment: both of data type are same , String type

Comment: Is your column nullable? Perhaps the equals in `q.billNum equals d.billNum` assumes that you also want `NULL == NULL` to match?

Comment: yes, the column is nullable.

Comment: Probably you haven't configured them as required. Do you really need them to be nullable? Because that's the reason why EF appends the criteria you are asking.

Comment: sounds i need to make the two field in db as not nullable, can i optimize the linq expression to avoid appending the SQL OR? if we make it, how can i write the linq expression. thanks a lot

Comment: You need to make the columns not nullable and **let EF know** that - either using `[Required]` attribute or fluent configuration. No need to touch LINQ query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what you can do in case you cannot change the `billNum` columns to be non nullable.

First, set the option mentioned by @Giorgi

```
class CurrentDBContext
{
    public CurrentDBContext()
    {
        Configuration.UseDatabaseNullSemantics = true;
        // ...
    }
}
```

Then change the LINQ query to **not use** `join`, but simple `where` like this

```
var orders = (from q in dao.CurrentDBContext.New_OrderForm 
              from d in dao.CurrentDBContext.New_OrderGoodsDetail
              where q.billNum == d.billNum
              select ...
```

The result will be the exact SQL query as the one you've shown (**with** `JOIN`!) without the `OR` part.

Comment: Just to emphasize that the join condition needs to be moved to the where as Ivan says. I had UseDatabaseNullSemantics = true, but still used the   on the join syntax, and didn't get the expect results

Answer (score 3):

It seems that Linq translates `q.billNum equals d.billNum` is such a way that it also includes a valid match in case both q.billNum and d.billNum are NULL (in SQL NULL is never equal to NULL, hence the OR in your query).

Making both fields non-nullable would be the best solution, provided both fields can never be NULL.

If this is not the case, you could also try to add a where clause in your Linq statement to specifiy that both q.billNum and d.billNum cannot be NULL. With any luck, Linq will recognize that nullable values are not possible.

Note: If you are working with Oracle you should check for empty strings as well as NULL (empty string is equivalent to NULL). Empty strings should be fine as a valid value in SQL Server.

As the above did not help, you could try to write the query yourself. If I'm not mistaking it would be something along the following lines (assuming `var` is an `List<Order>` in your example code - the results of your query should match the class you are using):

```
StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder();
query.AppendLine("SELECT [Extent1].[billNum] AS [billNum],");
query.AppendLine("       [Extent1].[orderSource] AS [orderSource],");
query.AppendLine("       [Extent1].[sourceOddNum] AS [sourceOddNum],");
query.AppendLine("       [Extent2].[PPT] AS [PPT]");
query.AppendLine("FROM [dbo].[New_OrderForm] AS [Extent1]");
query.AppendLine("INNER JOIN [dbo].[New_OrderGoodsDetail] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[billNum] = [Extent2].[billNum]");

List<Order> orders = DbContext.Database.SqlQuery<Order>(query.ToString()).ToList();
```

I have used similar workarounds to get around performance issues in the past.

Comment: Adding a `where` clause will not remove the "extra" `OR` condition (that would require EF to perform "global" optimization of the query expression). However, it could be that the SQL Server execution plan will benefit from knowing that `billNum` will never be `NULL`.

Comment: HI Sam, thanks for your detail response, right now  it maybe not feasible since the system is online , Customer does not allow me to make the field as non-nullable, i had tried this ' var orders = (from q in dao.CurrentDBContext.New_OrderForm.Where(p=>p.billNum!=null) 
                          join d in dao.CurrentDBContext.New_OrderGoodsDetail.Where(p=>p.billNum!=null) on q.billNum equals d.billNum',

Comment: and tried it also '  or 'from q in dao.CurrentDBContext.New_OrderForm 
                          from d in dao.CurrentDBContext.New_OrderGoodsDetail .Where(p=>p.billNum==q.billNum&& p.billNum!=null&& q.billNum!=null)''

Comment: it is pity ,the two approaches are not useful.:(

Comment: Thanks Sam,  it is good workaround as well, but i  have to  switch sql statement from linq code so that lots of linq code need to be change ,because lots of dynamical condition were appending in business logical code , as your mentioned ,the best workaround is to make the two field as non-nullable,  i need to persuade customer to change it. :):)

Answer (score 2):

Following on from @Giorgi's answer, the `UseDatabaseNullSemantics` flag will not work with the `equals` keyword - only the `==` operand. Thus in order to get round this and ensure the join on billNum is not part of the `OR` clause this approach should work (in conjunction with the `UseDatabaseNullSemantics` flag):

```
var orders = (from q in dao.CurrentDBContext.New_OrderForm 
          from d in dao.CurrentDBContext.New_OrderGoodsDetail 
          where q.billNum == d.billNum
          select new
         {    
            q.billNum,
            q.orderSource,
            q.sourceOddNum    
            d.PPT    
         }
```

This will generate the `JOIN` without the `OR`.

Comment: the second line, must be "from ..."  rather than "join ...". as join will expect the equals

Comment: Thanks - good spot given that the answer has been largely ignored! I've edited accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using EF6 try setting

```
context.Configuration.UseDatabaseNullSemantics = true;
```

and it will not generate NULL checks for those columns.

[According to documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.infrastructure.dbcontextconfiguration.usedatabasenullsemantics(v=vs.113).aspx)

> For example (operand1 == operand2) will be translated as: (operand1 = operand2) if UseDatabaseNullSemantics is true, respectively (((operand1 = operand2) AND (NOT (operand1 IS NULL OR operand2 IS NULL))) OR ((operand1 IS NULL) AND (operand2 IS NULL))) if UseDatabaseNullSemantics is false.

Comment: Actual testing indicates that this does not solve the problem (same SQL is generated). The SQL in the documentation is also different compared to what is in the question. I'm not sure what `UseDatabaseNullSemantics` really does.

Comment: exactly , i had a test, looks like the switch is not useful.:(

Comment: This worked perfectly for me. Setting the flag to true removed the SQL OR created on the nullable string comparison. Thanks @Giorgi.

Comment: just now i installed EF 6.1.3,  but it is still not working . :(

Comment: Sorry, I was using it in a where clause with the `==` operand (as per the example in the documentation). Having tested using the `equals` keyword on a join it does not have any effect. Frustrating!

Comment: @beyond8848, I've added an answer with a potential (clumsy) workaround.